# nginx rewrite if query string exists

Tags: nginx, rewrite, querystring

In the past a project was getting moved from `/` to `/subdir`. As the old URL structure was something like `/index.php?foo/123/bar` I used the following rewrite to get everything to `/forum`:

```
rewrite ^\/index\.php(.*)$ /forum/$1 last;
```

The problem with this rewrite is that it also redirects `/` to `/forum/` and `/index.php` to `/forum/`. Now I want to not redirect them because there has been created a new start page in `/`.

So `/` should not be redirected but if there is a query string it should.

I tried the following:

```
location / {
        if ($query_string !~ "") {
                rewrite ^\/index\.php(.*)$ /forum/$1 last;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
```

The start page works now but if there is a query string nothing gets rewritten and I don’t know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After half a day of silence I figured it out. By using the full `$request_uri` outside the location block and an adjustment to the regex to make any character after the `index.php` mandatory it works fine:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}

if ($request_uri ~* "^\/index\.php(.+)$") {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /forum/$1 last;
}
```